# IOS - Can i detect if a photo was taken by regular iphone app camera or by a third party application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm building an IOS applicaiton.

I'm want to get the last photo that was taken that was also took from the rugular iphone app camera and not by a third party application.

I can get the last photo from the photo library by this method:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

// Enumerate just the photos and videos group by using ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos.
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {

    // Within the group enumeration block, filter to enumerate just photos.
    [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];

    // Chooses the photo at the last index
    [group enumerateAssetsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(ALAsset *alAsset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *innerStop) {

        // The end of the enumeration is signaled by asset == nil.
        if (alAsset) {
            ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [alAsset defaultRepresentation];
            UIImage *latestPhoto = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[representation fullScreenImage]];

            // Stop the enumerations
            *stop = YES; *innerStop = YES;
```

Can i some how detect if this photo was taken by the regular iphone camera applicaiton?

Comment: You need to read exif information

Comment: What data exactly i need to read from the exif information?

Comment: I got the image "make" data.
If the make = apple , does that means that the regular camera application that tooked the picture was the default?